# Changing field identifiers without changing field names

Tags: django, django-forms

Another system makes requests to my server with parameters that look like `XYZ_LOGIN=myname&XYZ_PASSWORD=mydata`. I can't change that system nor the format.

I parse the data with such a form:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    XYZ_LOGIN = forms.CharField()
    XYZ_PASSWORD = forms.CharField()
```

But this is very ugly. Can I make fields with nice aliases like this?

```
   login = forms.CharField(alias='XYZ_LOGIN')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the field's [label](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#label):

```
XYZ_LOGIN = forms.CharField(label='Login')
```

As you say in the comments, this only makes the html output "human-friendly" when you render the form, you still have to use `cleaned_data.get('XYZ_LOGIN')` in your code.

There's no built in functionality similar to the 'alias' argument you propose. You could pre-process the post data before you instantiate the form, or customize the form behaviour. Personally, I would stick with the 'ugliness' of your current code.

Comment: This is for HTML representation of form. In python code i can access this field with `form.XYZ_LOGIN`, this is still ugly.